# Which ports are available with Ubuntu server

Tags: docker, web, server, webserver

I was wondering which ports are available for me to use for Web apps and which ones are system specific or system reserved.

A basic outline of the way the website works is a user creates and account and a docker container is created, that container sits on a port.

So if I have 100 users I need to know if there is enough ports available or if I have to do a redisign.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually  web servers will listen on 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS), all users will connect on one port, browsers usually connect   on one of the two ports I've mentioned.

Browsers usually connect to a website  on port 80 or 443 by default,  you can specify a custom port by a `:` then the port number after  the host name if the server  is using a custom port to serve the website.

for example a custom port would look like

```
http://stackoverflow.com:8080
```

where  8080 is the custom port.

For a list   of the common ports used in applications.  you can check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) out.

To  answer your  question, if you're not running the application that  listens  on that specific port then  you can use the port number for your  use.

Port numbers range from 0 to 65535, but only port numbers 0 to 1023 are reserved for privileged services and designated as well-known ports.

Comment: The list is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The [ephemeral port range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) is configurable, so you are not stuck with the defaults. There are tens of thousands, so if you have 100 users the number of ports should not be the breaking point, though the design of having a docker container for each users sounds odd to me.

I assume that your web server will front these containers so that the users don't connect directly to them? Allowing all those ports through the firewall would not be a good design!

Comment: Yeah that's exactly how it will work, the reason each user has a container is because there is a custom IDE built as a node application in each one, then if collaboration is required multiple users can ocupy a single container.

So for thee xample at the moment the url would show as www.example.com:8000
My aim to have it where the url displays the username instead of the port but for now I needed to ensure that there where enough ports for the plan to work.

Thank you for your comment.